# interface contains type constraints: cannot use interface in conversion

Tags: go, generics, constraints, type-parameter

```golang
type Number interface {
    int | int64 | float64
}

type NNumber interface {
}

//interface contains type constraints
//type NumberSlice []Number

type NNumberSlice []NNumber

func main() {
    var b interface{}
    b = interface{}(1)
    fmt.Println(b)

    // interface contains type constraints
    // cannot use interface Number in conversion (contains specific type constraints or is comparable)
    //a := []Number{Number(1), Number(2), Number(3), Number(4)}
    //fmt.Println(a)

    aa := []interface{}{interface{}(1), interface{}(2), interface{}(3), 4}
    fmt.Println(aa)

    aaa := []NNumber{NNumber(1), NNumber(2), NNumber(3), 4}
    fmt.Println(aaa)
}
```

why the `Number` slice `a` couldn't be initialized like that?

`NumberSlice` and `NNumberSlice` look like similarly, but what mean type constraints, it looks strange grammar

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The language specifications explicitly disallow using interfaces with  type elements as anything other than type parameter constraints (the quote is under the paragraph [Interface types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Interface_types)):

> Interfaces that are not [basic](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Basic_interfaces) may only be used as type constraints, or as elements of other interfaces used as constraints. They cannot be the types of values or variables, or components of other, non-interface types.

An interface that embeds `comparable` or another non-basic interface is also non-basic. Your `Number` interface contains a union, hence it is non-basic too.

A few examples:

```
// basic: only methods
type A1 interface {
    GetName() string
}

// basic: only methods and/or embeds basic interface
type B1 interface {
    A1
    SetValue(v int)
}

// non-basic: embeds comparable
type Message interface {
    comparable
    Content() string
}

// non-basic: has a type element (union)
type Number interface {
    int | int64 | float64
}

// non-basic: embeds a non-basic interface
type SpecialNumber interface {
    Number
    IsSpecial() bool
}
```

In the initialization of the variable `a`, you are attempting to use `Number` in a type conversion `Number(1)`, and this is not allowed.

You can only use `Number` as a type parameter constraint, i.e. to restrict the types allowed for instantiation of a generic type or function. For example:

```
type Coordinates[T Number] struct {
    x, y T
}

func sum[T Number](a, b T) T {
    return a + b
}
```

Comment: tks, I misunderstand between type and type parameter constraint

Comment: @HuangWei the confusion probably is that constraints **are** interface types, however when they include one or more types themselves the language allows only to use them in that specific way