# Type constraint (E) not met by embedding (E) in concrete struct

Tags: go, generics

I'm trying to implement a variation of the [pointer-method example for type-parameters](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#pointer-method-example) design pattern, in order to abstract over some unified repository interface.

I was under the impression that the `Person` struct would inherit the method-set of `Entity` if it composes `*Entity`, but I get a compile-time error as below. Could someone please explain why the type-constraint is not met and how to fix this code?

Apologies for the awful title; if someone could suggest an improved summary that would be fantastic (I'm quite new to Go).

Thanks :)

```golang
package main

// domain

type PEntity[E any] interface {
    *E
    SetID(id string)
}

type Entity struct {
    ID string
}

func (e Entity) SetID(id string) {
    e.ID = id
}

type Repository[E Entity, PE PEntity[E]] interface {
    Get(id string) *E
}

// data

type Person struct {
    *Entity
}

type PersonRepository interface {
    Repository[Person, *Person] // -> Person does not implement Entity
    AddPet(name string)
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint `E Entity` — syntactic sugar for `E interface{ Entity }` — effectively means that the **type set** of `E` includes exactly one type term `Entity`, which is a struct.

When you have exact constraints, you can only satisfy them with that very type, so it doesn't make much difference from not having the type parameter at all and declaring regular function arguments. As an example to help you understand:

```
func Foo[T int](v T) {}
```

is practically the same as:

```
func Foo(v int) {}
```

Therefore you can satisfy the constraint `E Entity` exclusively with the struct `Entity`.

Clearly `Person` is not `Entity`. Field embedding only affects the *method set* of the embedding type, which has no bearings on type identity.

If you change the constraint to a method-only (basic) interface — Or or change `Entity` directly ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nh1JERqrAfC)) —, then it will take only the method set into account and successfully compile:

```
type Repository[E interface{ SetID(id string) }, PE PEntity[E]] interface {
    Get(id string) *E
}
```

More about basic vs. non-basic interfaces: [interface contains type constraints: cannot use interface in conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71073365/interface-contains-type-constraints-cannot-use-interface-in-conversion/71076143#71076143)